# How i can update my subcollection with error : [firestore/not-found]?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to update on document on my subcollection but I have an error:

> Error: [firestore/not-found] Some requested document was not found.

First of all selected the good document on my collection Teams:

```
firestore()
  .collection("Teams")
  .where("tokenTeam", "==", "gvb2j3pcm9")
  .get()
  .then(async (querySnapshot) => {
    if (querySnapshot.empty) {
      console.log("no documents found");
    } else {
      querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
        let Teams = doc._data;
        console.log(Teams);

        // code below fits in here
      })
    }
  })
```

I have no error with the above code. Then I call my subcollection with just the statut in "attente" to select the one I want to update. My `console.log(members)` is working well.

After that I update the document selected I want to update which gives this error:

> Error: [firestore/not-found] Some requested document was not found.

```
// insert into above code
doc.ref
  .collection("membersList")
  .where("statut", "==", "en attente")
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    if (querySnapshot.empty) {
      console.log("no documents found");
    } else {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        let members = doc.id;
        console.log(members);
        doc.ref
          .collection("membersList")
          .doc(members)
          .update({
            statut: "Validé",
          });
      });
    }
  });
```

This is my data model:
[image: Image of Firebase Console showing Firestore structure]

Did I forget something?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the query you are making inside the `querySnapshot.forEach`. The `doc.ref` is representing a reference to the current document you are operating in the foreach, which is already a `memberList` document.

So what you are doing currently in your code is looking for the same document as a separate document in a subcollection contained in your original document, which won't work, in order to work all you have to do is this:

```
doc.ref
   .update({
       statut: "Validé",
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is your goal: For the given team token/ID, update all members who have a `"statut"` value of `"en attente"` to `"Validé"`.

As [@RafaelLemos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12857703) stated in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67106835/3068190), you only need to use `doc.ref` instead of `doc.ref.collection("membersList").doc(members)`. This mistake was caused by you shadowing the variable named `doc` and is why you should name your variables appropriately.

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67093194/3068190), you can search for requests the same way. As you find each document to update, rather than update it immediately as you have in your code, you should make use of a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to make a single atomic database write.

```
firestore()
  .collection("Teams")
  .where("tokenTeam", "==", "gvb2j3pcm9")
  .get()
  .then(async (matchingTeamsQuerySnapshot) => {
    if (matchingTeamsQuerySnapshot.empty) {
      console.log("no teams found");
      return;
    }
    
    // start a batched write
    const batch = firestore().batch();
    
    // for each team found, find members with "statut" of "en attente",
    // and queue updating "statut" to "Validé"
    await Promise.all(
      matchingTeamsQuerySnapshot.docs
        .map(async (teamDocSnapshot) => {
          // const teamData = teamDocSnapshot.data();
          // console.log(teamData);

          const memberRequestsQuerySnapshot = await teamDocSnapshot.ref
            .collection("membersList")
            .where("statut", "==", "en attente")
            .get();
          
          memberRequestsQuerySnapshot.forEach(memberRequestDoc => {
            batch.update(memberRequestDoc.ref, {
              statut: "Validé"
            });
          });
        })
    );
    
    // update the database all at once
    return batch.commit();
  })
```